# clang target is ignored

Tags: c++, c, windows, clang

Im trying to set a target when using clan compiler 5.0.0:

```
& "C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang" -v .\src\Filter.cpp -target powerpc-unknown-linux
```

> clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final) **Target:
>   powerpc-unknown-linux** Thread model: posix InstalledDir: C:\Program
>   Files\LLVM\bin  "C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" -cc1 -triple
>   powerpc-unknown-linux -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free
>   -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name MessageFilter.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix
>   -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu ppc -mfloat-abi hard -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -resource-dir "C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\5.0.0" -internal-isystem /usr/local/include
>   -internal-isystem "C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\5.0.0\include" -internal-externc-isystem
>   /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro
>   -fdebug-compilation-dir "C:\Source\Filter"
>   -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 120 -fno-signed-char -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o "C:\Users\kfir\AppData\Local\Temp\Filter-6f8e03.o" -x c++
>   **".\src\Filter.cpp" clang -cc1 version 5.0.0 based upon LLVM
>   5.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc**

Even though I have set the target as `-target powerpc-unknown-linux` it is ignored by the clang compiler, and it sets another value:

```
x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

I would very appreciate some help with that.

Comment: BTW, the same target is chosen is I set manually -mcpu :(

Comment: Just a guess but it could be that your clang doesn't support that triple so it's defaulting to its native target.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyP How can I tell if it does or doesn't? Just to note, that I need it as a cross-compiler for windows that supports powerpc

Comment: One thing you might try is ppc-unknown-linux, rather than powerpc

Comment: Tried it too, unfortunately, same result

Comment: Type `llc -version` and it will give you a list of the supported CPU architectures. On my installation (5.0.0), it supports `ppc32` and `ppc64` but not `ppc`.

Comment: I'm working on Windows in which I don't have llc (dunno why), checking "clang --version" instead gives the following: "C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin>clang --version
clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin"

Comment: Have you tried replacing powerpc with ppc64?

Comment: with ppc64 it still decides taking the default: "clang -cc1 version 5.0.0 based upon LLVM 5.0.0 default target i686-pc-windows-msvc"

Comment: I'm out of ideas then. I think your clang has probably only been built with support for Windows targets.

Comment: OK, Thanks. I would be greatful for an answer that will explain what I am seeing.